# Issue with directory index

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm building a php server (testing, I'm a newbie), wrote some code and then tried it. The problem is that the default index is `index.html`, so I removed it, and then I get this blank page.

Then, searching on the web I found about the `DirectoryIndex` command, but if I try this one I get `DirectoryIndex: invalid command`. What have I missed?

Comment: Please clarify. Tell us EXACLTY what have you done. In my thinking you deleted your script and now you dont know what to do, but somewhere you used that command

Comment: That file you deleted was your best friend right now. Bring him back. Open. Edit. Save.

Comment: Are you saying you had a file called `index.html` as the default home page for your new server setup, you deleted it in favor of your file, presumably `index.php` and then after that you got a blank page? If so, then you probably have a syntax error or some other fatal error in your php file

Comment: Sorry guys, i should have been more specific. The server i'm building is in index.php and I have not removed it, I have just removed index.html which is unused. But the system does not open my file index.php it just give me a blank page. So the specific question is: how can I do to make my index.php as the index page for the system?

Answer (score 0):

Just put

DirectoryIndex index.php (or whatever is your index file)

The DirectoryIndex command cannot be empty. This is the command that tells Apache which file to use as the index file. The server has no preferences by default and hence this is a required directive.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, it is obvious to me that the DirectoryIndex command cannot be empty. I tried DirectoryIndex index.php but I get the message: DirectoryIndex: invalid command

Comment: This means that the error is on some other line. Can I see your conf file? You can send it across on srajeprof@gmail.com